# CultureInfo("fr-BE") different on Windows 8.1 than before

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I set the culture for an .NET web app in order to use specific format for numbers, currency and date:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-BE");
```

On an Windows 2008 server machine with IIS 7 I get "d/m/yy" as short date format (what I want).
On my (new) Windows 8.1 pro machine (developer and test) I get "d-m-yy" format for the same CultureInfo..."dash" instead of "slash" separator.

I've checked also in Control Panel -> Region and the settings for French(Belgium) are as mentioned above, different in W2k8 server than in W8.1pro...

The .NET version is 4, which is ok. Invariant culture doesn't help, as far as I need specific culture to display in the UI and the problem was there. It is true, changes came with Windows 8... Finally I used to override some settings for the Thread culture, like the Date Separator:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat; if (dtfi.DateSeparator != "/") dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";
```

This ensure that slash will be the date separator all the time in the current thread.

Thank you.
Does anybody knows about it? Belgium changed national standards? Or, Microsoft did for them? Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: And what are their .NET Framework versions?

Comment: If you want a specific format, why not use the invariant culture?

Comment: According to [this site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Belgium) the formatting should be `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. .NET version is 4, which is ok. Invariant culture doesn't help, as far as I need specific culture to display in the UI and the problem was there. It is true, changes came with Windows 8...
Finally I used to override some settings for the Thread culture, like the Date Separator:
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
if (dtfi.DateSeparator != "/") dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";

This ensure that slash will be the date separator all the time in the current thread.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at similar issue for CultureInfo 'en-NZ', as it been changed for the same culture setting in different Windows version, and cause my web service saved different strings for the same CultureInfo, and it turns out it is provided by Windows since .Net Framework 4, and was a combination of Windows and .Net before that.

Lucky for me, I can make use of Invariant culture, which was recommended by Microsoft to make sure the string I saved into Database not going to be changed because of Windows or future .Net Framework update. The thing is, for my case it was the `AM\PMDesignator` changed from `a.m.\p.m.` to `AM\PM`, and the Invariant culture will make sure it saves to `AM\PM` I assume it will not change in the future, but if I want it save to `a.m.\p.m.` as it was for older version of Windows, Invariant culture wouldn't be able to do that, I will probably need define my own custom culture or overwrite the current culture as you did.

See the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34755478/301218) about Microsoft specified that CultureInof `are subject to change without notice`