# CultureInfo is not consistent between windows versions

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cultureinfo, windows-server-2012-r2

#### Has anyone noticed that on different versions of Windows the CultureInfo format will result in a different pattern?

Windows 7 created *dddd, MMMM dd, YYYY*

Sample output:
[Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feSqI.png)

Both Windows 10 & Windows Server 2012 created *dddd, MMMM d, YYYY*

Sample output:
[Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HPvy.png) &
[Server 2012 R2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irb6K.png)

I got this sample from the [MSDN site on DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(VS.85).aspx). Modified to check the leading Zero of day.

```
public class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string msg1 = "The date and time patterns are defined in the DateTimeFormatInfo \n" +
                      "object associated with the current thread culture.\n";

        // Initialize a DateTime object.
        Console.WriteLine("Initialize the DateTime object to May 06, 2001 3:02:15 AM.\n");
        DateTime myDateTime = new System.DateTime(2001, 5, 6, 3, 2, 15);

        // Identify the source of the date and time patterns.
        Console.WriteLine(msg1);

        // Display the name of the current culture.
        CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us");
        Console.WriteLine("Current culture: \"{0}\"\n", ci.Name);

        // Display the long date pattern and string.
        Console.WriteLine("Long date pattern: \"{0}\"", ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
        Console.WriteLine("Long date string:  \"{0}\"\n", myDateTime.ToLongDateString());

        // Display the long time pattern and string.
        Console.WriteLine("Long time pattern: \"{0}\"", ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
        Console.WriteLine("Long time string:  \"{0}\"\n", myDateTime.ToLongTimeString());

        // Display the short date pattern and string.
        Console.WriteLine("Short date pattern: \"{0}\"", ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
        Console.WriteLine("Short date string:  \"{0}\"\n", myDateTime.ToShortDateString());

        // Display the short time pattern and string.
        Console.WriteLine("Short time pattern: \"{0}\"", ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
        Console.WriteLine("Short time string:  \"{0}\"\n", myDateTime.ToShortTimeString());


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the docs for CultureInfo: "Except for the invariant culture, culture data is dynamic. This is true even for the predefined cultures. For example, countries or regions adopt new currencies, change their spellings of words, or change their preferred calendar, and culture definitions change to track this. Custom cultures are subject to change without notice, and any specific culture might be overridden by a custom replacement culture. Also, as discussed below, an individual user can override cultural preferences. Applications should always obtain culture data at run time."

Comment: @MikeZboray, I caught by surprise that en-NZ change the pattern 'tt' for TShortTimeStrting from 'a.m./p.m.' to 'AM/PM', and I spend lots of time looking though .Net announcements and documentations to figure out any indications when that change has been introduced into Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 (or earlier for WIndows Server). But indeed, `they are subject to change without notice`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there are far more CultureInfo's available on Windows 10. I hope this will be conistent with Windows Server 2016, and preferably pushed to all editions through WU.

For instance; Windows 10 has support for `247 regions` where as Windows 2012R2 only covers `142 regions`.

CultureInfo objects divided into regions:

Windows 10
[image]

Windows 2012R2
[image]

Comment: The date format and other culture properties changes depending windows server version as @gimlichael answers. Windows Server 2012: 
(ca Català dd/MM/yyyy H:mm)
(eu euskara yyyy/MM/dd H:mm)
(ca-ES-valencia Valencià (Espanya) dd/MM/yy HH:mm)
Windows Server 2016:
(ca català d/M/yyyy H:mm)
(eu euskara yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm)
(ca-ES-valencia valencià (Espanya) d/M/yyyy H:mm)

Comment: Does anyone knows where Microsoft informed about this?

Comment: @rasputino I am not sure, but it gets worse with the fact that Microsoft is switching to ICU over NLS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

If you prefer NLS where you host your code, you can consider using a complemental library i made for Globalization namespace: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cuemon.Extensions.Globalization#readme-body-tab